# Moving data from lite to pro mobile app

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I already have an app in iOS and Android app stores built using phonegap.  I am considering releasing a "pro" version of the app with increased functionality. What I am trying to figure out is how to migrate data for customers that already have the "lite" version and want to purchase the "pro" version.

I could probably create a data migration service in the lite version but I am not sure if that is the best approach.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS, this article

- [Lite To Paid iPhone Application Data Migrations With Custom URL Handlers](http://mobileorchard.com/lite-to-paid-iphone-application-data-migrations-with-custom-url-handlers/)

describes a mechanism to transfer data between two applications. The basic idea is that

- the "Lite" version of the app launches a URL with a custom URL scheme, containing the application data as Base64 encoded string,
- the "Pro" version of the app is registered for that custom URL scheme, and can decode the
  application data from the URL string when launched.

(I can say nothing about Android, but assume that Android solutions will look quite
different, so it may be sensible to make that a different question.)